# how set clang as default compiler instead gcc in debian

Tags: debian

I have to compile some libraries that need gcc 4.8 but I am on wheezy. another option is clang.

these are several libraries that downloaded automatically and called from installer so I can not modifies config to use clang.

how can I change default compiler to clang in debian instead?

Comment: Build scripts usually determine the "default compiler" by using the environment variable `CC`. Try to set it to clang and everything might work fine.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/clang 100
```

Comment: Just a note for g++ users, you also want `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/clang++ 100`